# Shared Printer in one network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printing, printer

Good day, I've been wondering about this issue on my network. I have a router in which port 1 is the only port that is working - as configured by the ISP. I bought a plug and play switch (TP-Link) to share the internet with other pc, CCTVs. Now, on my one PC where one of the printers is primarily installed. I shared the printer on the network, but when the PC is connected through LAN via a switch, I cannot print on the printer, But when I connect it through Wifi, I am able to print on that printer from another PC which is connected to wifi. so to summarize how can I print to a shared printer.
1. PC1 connected to LAN(switch) and PC2 wifi = can't print.
2. PC1 connected to wifi and PC2 connected on wifi = can print.
3. PC1 connected to LAN(switch) and wireless printer = can't print.
4. PC1 connected to wifi and wireless printer = can print.

Can anyone tell me where should I start digging and make a fix? I'm tired of plugging and unplugging the LAN cord every time I have to print through that shared printer.

Thank you.

Comment: by the way, it is a wireless router, provided by the ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Wireless and Wired are on the same subnet. Use your own main router (wireless with wired ports) to achieve this.

Set your printer up with a static IP on this network.

Install the printer driver on each device and point it to the printer.

Now everything can print. I do this just as described above.